# Application team getting JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI

Tags: ibm-mq

We are currently using web-sphere MQ 8.0..4,On linux machine.
Siel application connect to our queue manager with jndi. property and .binding files,earlier application working fine.but application upgraded from version 18 to 19 version also they have upgraded the java version from 1.7 to 1.8,post up gradation, application team facing below error. but we dont see any error in Queue manager logs. error written in application logs.
Application using below upgraded jdk version

```
D:\>java -version,java version "1.8.0_172",Java(TM) SE Run-time Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11),Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

Application uses MQ to communicate with the external systems. application jndi.property and .binding files

below jar files are related to websphere MQ version 8.0.0.7.

File based (current in config) application team needed the below JAR files, we have given below jar to application team which is related to MQ version 8.0.0.7 to.

```
a) jms.jar
b) fscontext.jar
c) connector.jar
d) providerutil.jar
e)  jta.jar  - optional
f) ldap.jar - optional
g) com.ibm.mq.jar (IBM)
h) com.ibm.mqjms.jar (IBM)
i) dhbcore.jar (IBM)- for MQ 7.5
j) com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
k) com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
l) com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi.jar
```

we have tried to placed the latest MQ client version( MQ client 9.0.0.7) jar files and tried it,but no luck we are facing same issue.
Application team tried placing one JAR at a time.which is available in my queue manager, While they have placed the all the JAR except JMS.Jar application team faced the below error:

```
ErrorCode = JMS_EXCEPTION 
ErrorMessage = Exception: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI.
The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem. 
See the linked exception for further information.; Message: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI. 
StackTrace = com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSFMQ6312: An exception occurred in the Java(tm) MQI. 
The Java(tm) MQI has thrown an exception describing the problem.
```

While placed all the Jar files including Jms.jar we get this error:

```
[SIEL ERROR]    Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-13,5,main]          [2:36:01.393 PM Tue Jul 23: ] Error:JNdi File
[SIEL ERROR]    Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-13,5,main]          [2:36:01.393 PM Tue Jul 23: ] Errorjava.lang.NullPointerException
```

@Josh: We have placed the 4 com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar, jms.jar (most be v2.0), fscontext.jar, and providerutil.jar, jar files post changes we are not getting earlier error( JMSFMQ6312),but now facing different exception in logs,please check below error.

```
Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-43,5,main]    [12:09:06.850 PM Mon Jul 29: ] Receive failed.
[SIEL ERROR]    Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-43,5,main]    [12:09:06.850 PM Mon Jul 29: ] Exception during Receive:
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: crmCF 
[SIEL ERROR]    Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-39,5,main]    [12:33:24.911 PM Mon Jul 29: ] Threw SielBusinessServiceException with 
ErrorCode = JMS_EXCEPTION
ErrorMessage = Exception: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'CRM.CUSTOMER.OUT'.
IBM MQ classes for JMS attempted to perform an MQGET; however IBM MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.; Message: JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'CRM.CUSTOMER.OUT'.
StackTrace = com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2002: Failed to get a message from destination 'CRM.CUSTOMER.OUT'.
IBM MQ classes for JMS attempted to perform an MQGET; however IBM MQ reported an error.
```

but we can see channel is running fine,no impact on messages transfer, application team wants to know why they are getting this exception.

```
AMQ8417: Display Channel Status details.
   CHANNEL(SIEL.CLIENT)                  CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
   CONNAME(xxx.xx.xx.xx)                   CURRENT
   STATUS(RUNNING)                         SUBSTATE(RECEIVE)
```

Comment: What is the version of the jms.jar that is included?   MQ v8 and later required JMS 2.0.

Comment: For MQ v8 or v9 you should ensure they DO NOT have `dhbcore.jar` or `connector.jar` since these are no longer needed and I have had apps get NullPointerException when they were still present since it means you are mixing versions it is not a good idea.  I would suggest that you have the app remove all of those jars and instead only include these 5: `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar`, `jms.jar` (most be v2.0), `fscontext.jar`, and `providerutil.jar`.

Comment: The allclient jar contains everything found in all the other `com.ibm.mq*` jars combined and was introduced at v8.0.  In v9.1 IBM even made the statement that the other jars are depreciated and you should only use `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar`.  Also ensure that the app does not have ANY other copies of the `com.ibm.mq*` jar files from older versions of MQ in the `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: @Josh:Thanks for your update, current jms.jar is related mq version 9.1.earlier we have tried with MQ version 8.0.0.4 jar files,still we are facing same issue.if CLASSPATH is pointing to older version jar files, should we remove those?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @Josh: We have placed the 4 com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar, jms.jar (most be v2.0), fscontext.jar, and providerutil.jar, jar files post changes we are not getting earlier error( JMSFMQ6312),but now facing different exception in logs,please check below error
.***********************************************************************************
Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-43,5,main] [12:09:06.850 PM Mon Jul 29: ] Receive failed.
[SIEL ERROR] Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-43,5,main] [12:09:06.850 PM Mon Jul 29: ] Exception during Receive:
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: crmCF

Comment: Edit the question and add the info in your comments to the question.

Comment: Something is referencing the JNDI name `crmCF` and is not able to resolve it.   By name it appears to be a connection factory.   Check your binding file is set up correctly.   Provide the linked exception for more info on the MQGET portion of the error.

Comment: @Josh; can you please help me on this what is the use of this  support packs"ms0n.zip, ms0B.zip, me01.zip and ms0n.tar " and from where we can download this,please provide us the links to download above support packs.

Comment: What does that have to do with this question?